# Java in getting places info from google map

Tags: java, html, api, google-maps

I have a JAVA programs in extracting data from url.

Extract.java

```
public class Uni_Extract {
    protected static String lat;
    protected static String lng;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Started");

        String csvFile = "C://Users/Kennedy/Desktop/university.csv";
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csvFile);

        for (int i=2; i<=2; i++){
            String url = "http://www.4icu.org/reviews/index"+i+".htm";

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();

            Elements cells = doc.select("td.i");

            Iterator<Element> iterator = cells.iterator();  
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Element cell = iterator.next();             
                String university = Jsoup.parse((cell.select("a").text())).text();
                String country = cell.nextElementSibling().select("img").attr("alt");
                LatLngBackup LatLngBackup = new LatLngBackup();
                LatLngBackup.getLatLongPositions(university);
                System.out.print(university);
                System.out.printf(", lat : %s, lng : %s %n", lat, lng);
                CSVUtils.writeLine(writer,Arrays.asList(country,university,lat,lng),',','"');
            }
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Then I also call a java class LatLng to call for latitude and longitude from Google map api.

```
public class LatLngBackup extends Uni_Extract
{
 public String[] getLatLongPositions(String address) throws Exception
  {
    int responseCode = 0;
    String api = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=" + URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8") + 
            "&key=AIzaSyCTBvomwAMvq0pSxgN0y2I_wALFJ8cx57Y";
    URL url = new URL(api);
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    httpConnection.connect();
    responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
    if(responseCode == 200)
    {
      DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();;
      Document document = builder.parse(httpConnection.getInputStream());
      XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
      XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();      
      XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/PlaceSearchResponse/status");
      String status = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
      if(status.equals("OK"))
      {
         expr = xpath.compile("//geometry/location/lat");
         super.lat = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
         expr = xpath.compile("//geometry/location/lng");
         super.lng = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
         return new String[] {lat, lng};
      }
      else
      {       
          super.lat="";
          super.lng="";
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

However, it gives me the message of reaching request limitation for the API key. Is there any other method that I can do the same?

Comment: maybe you should use  for example sigleton to prevent making connection each time you call this function. And for sure you should read something about OOP.

Comment: Pay a subscription to google services, so you can request all the data you need. Free API KEYs are for development purposes and have a request limit.

Comment: @shutdown-hnow May you please explain a bit more. I am not that expoertise in getting used with Google Map API and JAVA

Comment: @KennedyKan This is a matter of Usage limits, not really codewise.

Answer (score 0):

**"it gives me the message of reaching request limitation for the API key."**

[Usage limits](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage)

> The Google Places API Web Service enforces a default limit of 1 000
>   requests per 24 hour period, which you can increase free of charge. If
>   your app exceeds the limit, the app will start failing. Verify your
>   identity to get up to 150 000 requests per 24 hour period, by enabling
>   billing on the Google API Console. A credit card is required for
>   verification. We ask for your credit card purely to validate your
>   identity. Your card will not be charged for use of the Google Places
>   API Web Service.
>
> The limit for free usage is 150 000 requests per 24 hour period. If
>   your app exceeds the limit, the app will start failing again. Purchase
>   a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan license to get more than 150 000
>   requests per 24 hour period.

Free usage will only get you so far. Consider paying the [Premium License](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage#purchase-m4w) if you want more.

Addtional Reading:
For a full info on Usage and Limits, read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits).